# post-realm-principal-transformer appears not be working with custom JAAS realm in WildFly v30.0.1.Final

Tags: wildfly

I am implementing a custom JAAS realm using the [given example](https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/tree/main/jaas-realm). It implements the LoginModule and contains the below authentication method which is called upon a login attempt by user.

`public boolean login() throws LoginException`

I am also using a custom principal transformer as [per this example](https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/tree/main/custom-principal-transformer) to return a custom principal class. In my standalone.xml, I specified that my custom security domain will be using a post-realm-principal-transformer. According to [the documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/30/wildscribe/subsystem/elytron/security-domain/index.html), this attribute is supposed to do the below:

> A reference to a principal transformer to be applied after the realm has operated on the supplied identity name.

However, in my testing my custom principal transformer class **apply()** method (see below) was called before the **login()** method in the custom LoginModule implementation.

`public Principal apply(Principal t)`

I am retrieving additional information from a datasource using the **login()** method in the LoginModule implementation and storing them in a custom principal class. The **apply()** method is supposed to check if an instance of the custom principal class exists in the custom LoginModule implementation and retrieve it using the username as key. As a result of the **apply()** method being called before the **login()** method, this naturally failed.

Have anyone any experience with doing this? Is this behaviour expected and normal? Thanks for any insights.